# Not getting the expected result while using the .each() function

Tags: jquery

I am currently writing a js script in order to fetch DOM elements and push them to my database.

Basically, I would like to fetch the price, the name and the url of the products of my shopping cart.

I cannot figure out a way to use jquery to loop through the products of my shopping cart and console.log their name, price and url separately.

I know that I am doing something wrong in my .each function because I do not make use of ojb. After 3 hours of struggle I still havent figured out a way to get the expected result like:

name1
url1
price1

name2
url2 
price2

currently I get (assuming that I have two products in my cart):

name1name2
url1url2
price1price2

name1name2
url1url2
price1price2

here is my code, when I paste it in the chrome console I get the above described result:

```
$.get(window.location.href, function(data){ 

    $("tr.woocommerce-cart-form__cart-item.cart_item").each(function(i, obj) {



    const name = $('td.product-name').text();
    console.log(name);

    const url = $('a.woocommerce-LoopProduct-link.woocommerce-loop-product__link').attr('href');
    console.log(url);

    const price = $('span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount').text();
    console.log(price);

})
})
```

I would be very thankful if someone could release me from this struggle :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `obj` as the 2nd parameter of your jQuery selectors:

```
const name = $('td.product-name', obj).text();
const url = $('a.woocommerce-LoopProduct-link.woocommerce-loop-product__link', obj).attr('href');
const price = $('span.woocommerce-Price-amount.amount', obj).text();
```

This tells jQuery to only search within the current `obj` in the `each` iteration.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, I didn't know how to make use of obj. You saved me a lot of headache :-)

Comment: Or use `this` instead of `obj`